# StringTokenizer not working properly with delim "//"

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

I am trying to break string on delim "//". My string also contains "/" and StringTokenizer giving strange result, it also break string on "/".

```
  String  mStr = "abcd//aaa//32434//3/34343";
        StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(mStr, "//");
        while(tok.hasMoreTokens()){
            System.out.println(tok.nextToken());
        }
```

the result is

```
abcd
aaa
32434
3
34343
```

And the expected result is

```
    abcd
    aaa
    32434
    3/34343
```

Why this is happening and what is the solution of it? I do not want to replace "/" with other characters.

Comment: what is expected result?

Comment: i have updated expected result in question @NikolayKuznetsov

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`StringTokenizer` takes both the tokens as separate, and tokenizes on both of them. So, it is tokenizing on both `//` and `/`, and hence the result.

---

I would rather prefer [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) over `StringTokenizer`. It's easier to use, and has more options. It can take `Regex` as parameter, and returns an `array` of `tokens` which you can use later on: -

```
String  mStr = "abcd//aaa//32434//3/34343";

String[] arr = mStr.split("//");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

**Output : -**

```
[abcd, aaa, 32434, 3/34343]
```

Answer (score 3):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html:

> An instance of StringTokenizer behaves in one of two ways, depending on whether it was created with the returnDelims flag having the value true or false:
>
> - If the flag is false, delimiter characters serve to separate tokens. A token is a maximal sequence of consecutive characters that are not delimiters.
> - If the flag is true, delimiter characters are themselves considered to be tokens. A token is thus either one delimiter character, or a maximal sequence of consecutive characters that are not delimiters.

`StringTokenizer` will always split on consecutive delimiter characters, not on the delimiter string itself. Thus, your split is "any number of slashes or slashes". `//` is two slashes or slashes; `/` is one slash or slash. Thus, your `StringTokenizer` will match both of the sequences as separators.

In other words, your `StringTokenizer` is equivalent to splitting on the following regular expression: `[//]+`, and not `//` as you thought.

Answer (score 2):

`StringTokenizer` is a very simple class. If you want a tokenizer-like functionality, you can use [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), as it considers delimeter string as a regular expression.

```
    String mStr = "abcd//aaa//32434//3/34343";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(mStr);
    scanner.useDelimiter("//");
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**-** `split()` method of `String` would do just fine, with `//` with `delimiter`.

```
public class Reg {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String s = "abcd//aaa//32434//3/34343";
        String[] arr = s.split("//");

                for (String x : arr){

            System.out.println(x);
        }
       }
}
```